# solr with pf and qf search together

Tags: php, apache, solr

I am using php solr extension and what to do a search in solr as follow:

```
        $dismaxQuery = new SolrDisMaxQuery($search);
    $dismaxQuery
        ->addQueryField("fundraise_title", 10)
        ->addQueryField("fundraiser_display_name", 10)

        ->setPhraseFields("fundraiseTitleExact~2^10 fundraiserDisplayNameExact~2^10");
```

this returns the following response header:

```
[params] => SolrObject Object
    (
        [pf] => fundraiseTitleExact~2^10 fundraiserDisplayNameExact~2^10
        [fl] => frpId,fundraise_title
        [indent] => on
        [q] => The Nest
        [qf] => fundraise_title^10 fundraiser_display_name^10
        [wt] => xml
        [hl] => true
        [defType] => edismax
        [version] => 2.2
    )
```

but when doing the search, it seems that the search is only done on the qf query and pf query is ignored; any idea how to make this work together?

solr input:

```
params={pf=fundraiseTitleExact~2^10+fundraiserDisplayNameExact~2^10&fl=frpId,fundraise_title&indent=on&q=The+Nest&qf=fundraise_title^10+fundraiser_display_name^10&wt=xml&hl=true&defType=edismax&version=2.2}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal and expected behaviour:

**qf** is a query fields, which mean, that these fields are used to be search against them.

pf is a phrase fields, which only boost results, which you get from **qf**, that's why you may think that they are ignored.

From **Solr** documentation:

> The pf (Phrase Fields) Parameter. Once the list of matching documents
>   has been identified using the fq and qf parameters, the pf parameter
>   can be used to "boost" the score of documents in cases where all of
>   the terms in the q parameter appear in close proximity. The format is
>   the same as that used by the qf parameter: a list of fields and
>   "boosts" to associate with each of them when making phrase queries out
>   of the entire q parameter.

Comment: ok, now I understand a bit better, but what is still unclear is the behaviour when:  1 I have in qf participantFname field and I use field participantFnameExact in pf . Can you give me a concrete working example with explanations?  Thank you.